# Apple Pencil with Pages

Tags: ios, ipad, pages

I use Pages on my iPad pro and would like to edit using my new Apple Pencil - can anyone tell me how to get Pages to recognise the Apple Pencil? Would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you simply have to plug the Apple Pencil in your iPad and wait a couple seconds until it is detected...

Answer (score 2):

As of Pages version 4.0 the Apple Pencil is now supported.  This [Apple Support for the iOS version of Pages](https://help.apple.com/pages/ipad/4.0/#/tane3a18e6f4) explains how to use the Apple Pencil to draw, mark up and otherwise manipulate a Pages document.

From Apple:

> Use Apple Pencil: Tap and hold Apple Pencil anywhere on the page.
> Draw anywhere on the page or in the drawing area; you can do any of the following at any time:
>
> - Switch drawing tools: Tap any of the tools at the bottom of the screen.
> - Change colors: Tap the current color at the bottom of the screen, then tap a new one. Swipe left to fine-tune your color.
> - Resize the drawing area: Drag any of its handles.
> - Adjust the color’s opacity: If you’re using the pen, pencil, crayon, or paint tool, tap it then drag the slider.
> - Adjust the stroke size (line thickness): If you’re using the pen, pencil, crayon, or eraser, tap it then tap a stroke size.
>   [image: Using drawing features]

Answer (score 1):

As of the time I am writing this, the pencil doesn't work with Pages.app except as a pointer. It can do whatever you can do by pointing/touch, but you can't draw or annotate.

[I researched this on Apple Support](https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7897679?start=0&tstart=0) and elsewhere, as I was hoping I could draw within the application.

One possible workaround is to export a pdf or image of the page and annotate in another application.